# Can I put spacing in Application Pool Name when creating a new web application in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I'm currently configuring a SharePoint Farm, and I'm not sure what is the right naming convention for Application Pool Name in creating a new web application. Is it okay if it has spacing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, the Default pool is called "Default App Pool" with spaces and all. I personally would avoid them in case you need to access them in a URL or something similar where you would need a %20 to mimic a space. But no harm in a space.